# Library not loaded X / Multiple commands produce X, but only on some environments

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, fbsdkloginkit

CI and all developer environments had zero issues until a single laptop environment stopped being able to build the iOS app. The error thrown was `Library not loaded: @rpath/Foo.framework/Foo`

Adding this `Foo` framework manually via Xcode resolved the problem.

[image: Xcode – Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content]

HOWEVER, it broke the builds on CI and all other developer environments. Those are now throwing the error

```
Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-adwcstkmsmzcjgdzgisfheqwwytp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/Foo.framework'
```

So we have a seesaw situation where fixing the issue on one environment breaks it on the others.

We have checked the versions of all major pieces of the toolchain (Xcode, iOS, Flutter, Cocoapods) and they are the same across all environments. We have tried reinstalling Xcode and using a fresh repository on the problematic laptop environment.

Comment: What distinguishes the failing env from the old ones? What’s unique about it? I think fixing why the build cant see the library should be done in another method besides xcode, ie fixing the issue preventing it from being seen. Because the other envs can import it fine.

Comment: There's no obvious difference about the failing environment, unfortunately. I have very little experience with this type of issue on iOS so I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Did you try changing the xcode build settings to legacy build system on the failing env? Or what is on the functional ones?

Comment: Or importing it in xcode for the failing env, but running pod deintegrate and reinstalling the pods in the env that were previously functional but broke after the manual insert.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not resolve this for everyone, but in my case it did resolve the problem.

Apparently this line was added to my `.zshrc` at some point, I think it was recommended by brew during installation of something. In any case, I was getting errors when trying to run `arch -x86_64 pod update` until I removed this:

```
# ruby
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed after I updated cocoapods to 1.12.0. You also need to remove the FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKCoreKit_basic from Frameworks, libraries and Embedded Content section